# Update edge with upsert in OrientDB v3.0.3

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to implement this new upsert edge feature available with v3.0.3 but getting exception `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error updating edge: 'out' is not a vertex.`
I have created a class `Person` with `Name` field as unique index and `Friend` with field id as unique index. 
Command issued : `UPDATE EDGE Friend SET in = (SELECT FROM Person WHERE Name = 'name1' ) , out = (SELECT FROM Person where Name = 'name2') , id = 'f1' UPSERT WHERE id = 'f1'`. Please let me know if I am using this correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you open an issue on github? Thx

Comment: Hi , yes I have opened two related tickets for this issue https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/8406 and https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/8424